# lodash dependency in a Gutenberg plugin

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I'm taking my first steps in Gutenberg block development and I'm already stuck. My block JS script makes use of a couple lodash functions (`filter` and `pick`). I'm registering my block using the following function:

```
function register_block() {
    wp_register_script(
        'block-script',
        plugins_url( 'block.build.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-utils', 'lodash' )
    );

    register_block_type( 'my/block', array(
        'editor_script' => 'block-script',
    ) );
}
```

As you can see I'm adding the lodash lib as a dependency, and checking the page source code it's effectively loaded before my plugin's script. However, I'm getting a `ReferenceError: pick is not defined` console error.

This is the line that calls the `pick` function:

```
onSelectImages( images ) {
    this.props.setAttributes( {
        images: images.map( ( image ) => pick( image, [ 'alt', 'caption', 'id', 'url' ] ) ),
    } );
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related core ticket [#43733](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43733) for replacing underscore with lodash.

Comment: Are you just calling `pick` as is? Can you edit your question with the line of code in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the block script I had to replace:

```
import pick from 'lodash/pick';
```

with:

```
const { pick } = lodash;
```

And now it seems to work for me.

Comment: Just as a note for future visitors, the first code block above is for bundler/compilers like webpack/parcel. That will include the `pick` functionality as part of your bundle. The second code block is runtime code making the `pick` functionality available from the global lodash library. Of course, the global lodash object must be available at the time the line runs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that lodash isn't a script dependency, it's an NPM dependency:

```
array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-utils', 'lodash' )
```

You can't enqueue it this way and expect your application to build. Lodash may be available in WP Admin, but webpack runs in a local Node CLI context, and it doesn't know what `lodash` is. So instead you need to use `npm` to acquire the library and include it in your final JS build via babel/webpack/etc. This way webpack/babel know about `lodash` and can do their job correctly.

Comment: But Gutenberg itself adds it that way: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/lib/client-assets.php#L75

Comment: This is incorrect. Since the block editor requires lodash to be an available script, it _is_ available to other scripts via `wp_enqueue_script`. Of course, you *can* `require` the file via npm and include it in your bundle, but that's unnecessarily increasing your bundle size.

Comment: @JakeParis on the page lodash is available yes, but that's not the problem the OP is asking about, webpack/babel aren't running in WP Admin, they're running in a Node context, they don't know lodash is available on the webpage when they're building the bundle, or how to deal with it

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clarifing your answer. There are 2 possible solutions to the OP, and yours is the one, and switching out the `import` statement for the destructuring of lodash is the other. The problem with this solution it's a waste to include lodash in the bundle just to make the build tool know what is meant by `pick`, _as long as it's known_ that lodash will be available in the global context.